# Can 只有 be used in this context?

Tags: grammar, usage

My Chinese teacher recently introduced us to the character 只. Specifically, using it to mean "only".

However, all of the examples that she gave were things, like:

```
A:你有没有X和Y？

B:没有Y，我只有X。
```

As in, to use 只 to specify only one out of a list of different things. However, I was curious, could you use 只 to indicate a smaller number of something? For example, could you say something like:

```
A:你有三件旗袍。对不对？

B:不对。我只有两件旗袍。
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. It's quite right Chinese.

Comment: YES! Of course you can! Good thinking!

Comment: Yes you can. `只` not just means "only one of", but also means "only part of". eg: Q:Do you finished cooking? A:No, I 只 cooked vegetable A, vegetable B, meat C, I haven't cooked meat D, vegetable E, and the soup F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“只” means “by no means more than”，“only”.
If you add this word, this means you have no more than ……, **at most** I have……

Compare:

1) I have **no more than** 2 dresses（我**只有**2件衣服）

2) I have 2 dresses（我有2件衣服，可能还有，但是未提及）

Comment: Probably being pedantic, but "no more than" is slightly vague. If I have "no more than two dresses", it could be that I only have one dress, so "only" is a better approximation for 只, at least per the understanding I have of the word.